# c# Combine byte array and convert to a 16-bit Integer

Tags: c#, arrays

Lets say I have a byte array defined like this:

```
byte[] byteArray = { 0x08, 0x00 };
```

I need to combine the elements in the array to create:

```
0x0800
```

Then convert that to an int:

```
2048
```

Something like this:

```
    private static int GetMessageType(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        if(byteArray.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteArray");

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Two bytes does not make an Int32... What rules do you want for the conversion here?

Comment: bits 0 through 15 would be the Int16 and bits 16 through 31 would be zero.  So 0x0800 would be: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use simple bitwise operators? e.g.

```
byte hiByte = byteArray[0];  // or as appropriate
byte lowByte = byteArray[1];
short val = (short)((hiByte << 8) | lowByte);
```

In this case the bitwise result is treated as a [signed] `short` (following the title?) and could result in a negative value, but that can be altered as needed by just removing the cast ..

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`BitConverter.ToInt16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16.aspx), except it appears that you want a BigEndian conversion.  So use Jon Skeet's `EndianBitConverter`: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

Comment: I used a decompiler on Jon Skeets .dll and it looks like his EndianBitConverter uses the same bitwise operations pst suggested.

Comment: @aelstonjones: Right, but one is more self-explanatory when you see it again.